# Windows 8 Keyboards stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, input-device

I have no idea what happened, but now none of my keyboards are working.

I have an HP PS/2 keyboard that I use on my computer. A couple of minutes ago I stepped away from my computer and when I came back the keyboard wasn't working. It didn't respond to anything I did no matter how much I banged on the keys.

I assumed the keyboard was broken, so I tried a different USB keyboard, but that one didn't work either!

Answer (score 2):

Some time Windows doesn't recognize keyboard, or doesn't recognize some keys.
So for that Microsoft provides one s/w that fix it automatically that is called Microsoft Fix it. Use it may be it will help you out.
Here is the link:

[Microsoft Fix it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/troubleshoot-keyboard-problems)

Comment: Or may be this one also helpful:                        http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kvosters/archive/2013/02/19/quick-fix-windows-8-keyboard-stopped-working.aspx

Comment: If anyone get the solutions by this can mark the answer as a selected answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good chance Filter Keys was accidentally enabled. This is the case if holding down a key for a long time will allow it to register normally. For example, while on the desktop, hold down the Windows key for about 3 seconds, then release it (this should bring up the start menu normally).

To disable it, go to Control Panel -> Ease of Access, and under "Ease of Access Center" click the link that says "Change how your keyboard works". Under the "Make it easier to type" section, there is a checkbox for "Turn on Filter Keys". Disable this and click "Apply". Keyboard should be back to normal now.