# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error when starting win 10 game app

Tags: windows-10-preview, visual-c++, runtime-error

I get a "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error" when I start my game "Royal Revolt 2", an app from the Windows 10 store. The error leads to a `licensemanager.exe` files in my windows, system 32 folder.

I have reinstalled the game twice, disabled my antivirus. and did the command prompt action `bcdedit.exe /set increaseUSER VA 2800` and restarted my computer. None of this suggestions worked.

Shall I assume that this is just a problem relating to Win 10, itself? However, the app did work fine before some of my last updates were installed on my computer with the "slow ring" setting. Does anyone else have an idea?

Comment: Which game? Is it a Store app?

Comment: yes, it's royal revolt 2.

Comment: It sounds like the game does not support Windows 10 despite being on the Windows Store, the fact its using Visual C++ is odd.  I would contact the developer for assistance you might be missing the C++ Runtimes.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 includes the Visual C++ Runtimes for store apps.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 - That doesn't mean the application is a Universal Application

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you got this game from somewhere and that you didn't write it yourself (there's the visual-c++ tag which might mean that you wrote it).

The error is an "exception" raised by the license manager. That probably means that it thinks you don't have a valid license to run this game.

If you got it through a legitimate source I would suggest going back to that source and asking them what's up. Perhaps it wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: i simply downloaded it from the windows app store. But i will ask.

Comment: I have reinstalled it, but it gave me the same error as well.

Answer (score -1):

> `Case 1:`

If you have Antivirus in your laptop/PC then it may give an error just disable your antivirus when you want to play the game and enable it after finish the game.

> `Case 2:`

If antivirus is not installed then open using Ctrl+Shift+Esc windows task manager end the process of this Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime.

> `Case 3:`

If still It gives you an error It may happen because of not installed properly of your Graphics card.

Comment: case 1: antivirus disabled..same result
case 2: the process isn't running at all when I searched for it
case 3: I do have a windows update for my driver, i'll see if that fixes it. I didn't install it because i already had that update on a newer build.

Comment: See this and do as appropriate [Microsoft Fix it](http://superuser.com/questions/786040/windows-8-keyboards-stopped-working/871534#871534) download it and try again, and if it still gives you an error say it.

Comment: This link surely help you out of this problem [Runtime Error Solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b5d10db8-2980-4fe6-81e0-f232eab4037a/need-fix-for-microsoft-visual-c-runtime-library-runtime-error?forum=itprovistaapps)

Comment: Microsoft Fix it isn't supported in win 10, i just went to the website and it said so. Trying out the Runtime Error Solution right now.

Comment: The solution didn't work. It is still giving me the error.

Comment: May this one [Solution](http://steamcommunity.com/app/236430/discussions/0/558754259803970534/)

Comment: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzuWLno8Rfg)

Comment: The video didn't work.

Comment: Now you need to reinstall your game or License problem might be there!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. The last thing would be that win 10 is still fixing it's bugs. This all happened after a few updates since the game wasn't popping up this error before.

Comment: So the only solution I tell you is that get back your older version and play the game until & unless Win 10 fixes all bugs successfully.